# Is www-authenticate close client connection?

Tags: c, tcp

My program is server-client model.
when client Get localhost:25000, server respond 401 status code with www-authenticate header.

```
      newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
      //TODO: accept connection
      //TODO: send 401 message(more information about 401 message : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication) and authentificate user
      //close connection
      char buffer[9000];
      int bytes = 0;
      bytes = recv(newsockfd, buffer, 1500, 0);

      char message[] = "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized\r\nWWW-Authenticate: Basic realm='localhost'\r\nContent-Type: text/html;\r\n\r\n";
      int length = strlen(message);
      
      while (length > 0) {
          printf("send bytes : %d\n", bytes);
          bytes = send(newsockfd, message, length, 0);
          if(bytes==-1){
            continue;
          }
          length = length - bytes;
      }
      
      char parser[5] = "Basic";
      int flag = 0;
      int received = 0;
      printf("Token : %s , tokensize : %d\n", token, tokensize);
      char c;

      bytes = 0;
      // shutdown(newsockfd, SHUT_RDWR);
      // close(newsockfd);
      // newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);

      
      bytes = recv(newsockfd, buffer, 1500, 0);
```

here is the code that server recv client request and send 401 message

the problem is when I call recv twice.( last line)
recv always return 0, and that mean connection was closed.

I'm using http1.1,BSD socket. so it works with persistent connection I think.

when I add commented lines, It works properly.

Question
request with www-authenticate header close connection?

Comment: `char parser[5] = "Basic"` needs a little basic math. Tip: `char* parser = "..."` is much harder to mess up.

Comment: Tip: `length -= bytes`.

Comment: Have you used a tool like Wireshark to see what's actually being sent, or if anything at all is being sent?

Comment: Persistent connection are an option which the client can use if the server agrees. Neither server nor client can enforce use of persistent connections. Apart from that your message sending is broken if it does not work on the first try since you always start with message again instead of continuing with the parts which were not sent yet.

Comment: http 1.1 has persistent connection by default  I know... Is the Connection: keep-alive  
header required?